# Bootstrap tooltip line break in title

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm using the html code as follows to show the bootstrap tooltip.

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-3 offset-sm-1 align-self-center"> <a href="#forb" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm btn-block" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="or call us at <br><strong>+852 12345678</strong>" data-placement="bottom" >Reserve Table</a>  </div>
```

And i initialized the tooltip as :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[data-toggle="tooltip"]").tooltip();
});</script>
```

All works fine but the problem is the content available in title not displayed with the spaces....It removes all the new lines and show it in the single line ....How can i overcome this? 
Also i want it in black color but it displays it in white color

Comment: You've already done so but it should be noted that `data-html="true"`  must be included. Are you unable to render any html in your tooltip or is it just line breaks that don't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the single quote for your tooltip initialization. I have tested with Bootstrap 4.5.0 and it is working fine.

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="col-12 col-sm-3 offset-sm-1 align-self-center">
  <a href="#forb" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm btn-block" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="or call us at <br><strong>+852 12345678</strong>" data-placement="bottom">Reserve Table</a>
</div>
And i initialized the tooltip as :
```

Comment: Yeah i did that but still its not working.could it be a browser or editor issue ? im using sublime text editor.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. Did you run the code snippet and copy the code to your text editor? If your tooltip has not initialized properly, you won't get the desired result. Did you see any error in your browser?

Comment: For example, if using a double quote, below error, will be shown: 
Error {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 23,
  "colno": 7
}

Comment: @bsk Tooltips rely on the 3rd party library Popper.js for positioning. You must include popper.min.js before bootstrap.js or use bootstrap.bundle.min.js / bootstrap.bundle.js which contains Popper.js in order for tooltips to work!

Comment: <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: Uncaught  jquery.slim.min.js : 2 Error: TOOLTIP: Option "html" provided type "string" but expected type "boolean".    at Object.typeCheckConfig (util.js:146)
    at a.I._getConfig (tooltip.js:630)
    at new a (tooltip.js:130)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (tooltip.js:691)
    at Function.each (jquery.slim.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.each (jquery.slim.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.a._jQueryInterface [as tooltip] (tooltip.js:682)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):247)
    at l (jquery.slim.min.js:2)
    at c (jquery.slim.min.js:2)  <-- this is the error but i didnt understand

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand the error as well on jquery.slim.min.js. But, you may want to update your scripts to the latest version as per stated in the code above.

Comment: code snippet is working properly. i copied it but still didnt work.

Comment: Don't mention, didn't help much.